# theorem 2.22 in Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9LPf.jpg)
I understood the fact that $m(K)=0$, and it holds for every compact $K\subset A_t$. But I can't understand $m(A_t)=0$.
If $A_t=A\cap (E+t)$ is compact, $m(A_t)=0$ holds (note that "for every compact $K$") but sets $A, (E+t)$ are neither closed or compact (consider the fact that an intersection of compact and closed set in a Hausdorff space is compact).
How to justify $m(A_t)=0$ ?

Comment: Lebesgue measure is _regular_. In RCA we know this as soon as Lebesgue measure is introduced, since it's constructed  via the Riesz Representation Theorem. What does "regular" mean here?

Comment: In this context, "regular" means $m(E)= \rm{sup}\{m(K) |K\subset E\}$ for every open, Lebesgue measurable $E$, every compact $K$.

Comment: Nope. You need to get the definition straight, then the answer to your question will be clear.

Comment: Oops. To be fair, all that RRT states explicitly is inner regularity for open sets. But see Definition 2.15 and then Proposition 2.17.b.